# Change image when page refresh sometimes keep loading same image

Tags: javascript

im using this script to rotate and change image when the page is refresh it working ok but sometimes it keep loading the same image several times before change to the new image, is there a way to fix this?

```
var theImages = [
      "1.jpg",
      "2.jpg",
      "3.jpg"
      ];
      function changeImage(){
      var size=theImages.length;
      var x = Math.floor(size*Math.random())
      document.getElementById("headerbanner").src = theImages[x];
    }

onload=changeImage
```

Comment: You're not "rotating" the image — you are randomly picking one image out of an array of _N_ images ... and the nature of randomness is that you certainly can pick the same image twice in a row. or even 20 times in a row.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve the image rotation behaviour that you require, you'll need to "remember" some state (ie the image that your were previously up to) between page loads. One easy way to do this is vial the [LocalStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

You can for instance, retrieve a previously stored value for a key via:

```
let lastIndex = localStorage.getItem('last_index');
```

And then use that to control which image is displayed from your array. You would also use:

```
localStorage.setItem('last_index', `${ lastIndex }`)
```

To update the stored value, for the next page reload. Together, these might integrate with your code like this:

```
  /* Get the last stored index, and parse to an integer */
  let lastIndex = Number.parseInt(localStorage.getItem('last_index'))

  if(Number.isNaN(lastIndex)) {
    /* If we got an invalid index (ie no previously stored value) set to default 0 */
    lastIndex = 0;
  }
  else {
    /* Otherwise increment the index counter. This is going to cause the image to
    change every page load */
    lastIndex ++; 
  }

  /* Remember the updated index for future reloads */
  localStorage.setItem('last_index', `${ lastIndex }`)

  var theImages = [
    "1.jpg",
    "2.jpg",
    "3.jpg"
    ];

    function changeImage(){

    var size=theImages.length;

    /* Use the modulo operators to get x based on lastIndex, and the total number
    of images */
    var x = lastIndex % size;

    document.getElementById("headerbanner").src = theImages[x];
  }

  window.onload=changeImage
```

Remember to keep in mind that the LocalStorage API sets values as `strings`, which is why `Number.parseInt()`,etc is necessary.

Comment: Hard to look at in a comment, but ... `index = (1 * localStorage.getItem('last_index') + 1) % imgs.length; localStorage.setItem('last_index', \`${index}\`);`

Comment: @StephenP nice, some clever use of type coercion there! I opted for the more verbose approach to make the code a little easier to understand in case some of the ideas in my answer were new concepts for user2309197 . Thanks for the comment :-)

Answer (score 1):

A good way to achieve the rotation after refresh would be to save your previous image index in the url and change it each time.

1) you land on the page, the query parameter image  is empty, you get image with index 1 and you set your url to mysite.com?imageid=1

2) you refresh, the query parameter is 1, you set it to 2 in the url and display the image (there is no randomness here but you never get the same image)

3) implement custom logic to fit any index, you can implement randomness !== to previous image id to always get a different image with a recursive while loop:

```
while (newImageId === queryParam.imageId) { getRandomImageId(queryParam.imageId)}
```

I am on my phone can't write the code but you can use window.location for the url

Answer (score 1):

Save the current image into the local session.

```
localStorage.setItem('lastImage', imageIndex);
```

After page load...

```
localStorage.getItem('lastImage');
```

... and exclude it from your random mechanism or ever iterate.